# redirecting serial command to TCP/IP

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a script which can be run from python terminal and it will start a cherrypy server. 
At localhost, it will return a web app which when user press a button, it will send serial command to a device through the serial port (TX, RX, GND). 
What i wanted to do is to redirect the serial command from serial port to the Ethernet. 
One of the options that i found was to use TCP/IP serial bridge found here: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#tcp-ip-serial-bridge

But then, what should i do next? I don't really know  what that "tcp_serial_redirect.py" script is going to do with my script. Could someone explain it to me or is there anywhere that I can find better explanation?

My guess would be to call/run the script in my script. But should i run it ONLY when i am sending serial command? or should i import that script at the start?

Comment: This is Website+Serial Communication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684977/python-and-arduino-serial-communication

Comment: @User how does this question related to that :? i could get my serial port working just that i want to transfer it over TCP/IP

Comment: I do not fully understand: "What i wanted to do is to redirect the serial command from serial port to the Ethernet." Is it you want to do ethernet via serial or do you want a webbrowser send commands to something like an arduino?

Comment: okay, the situation is like this. both the devices can communicate two-way via the serial port. but at the same time, they have ethernet cable that is able to communicate as well. So, i think it is possible to just use the ethernet cable to communicate and so i can remove the serial physical link between them.

Comment: What does the serial communication is actually doing?, an example to use the tcp-serial-bridge is have both computers at a remote location and use the bridge to communicate with the public host and write to a TCP socket as if it was a serial device right beside you: YOUR_COMPUTER -> PUBHOST[TCP_PORT:8080] -SERIAL->  PRIVHOST, and the PRIVHOST can be any device with a serial port connected to the PUBHOST. Thats the idea of the script. But for what are you actually using the serial ports?, can you just not use it at all?, do you have any alternative method to communicate?